# airflow postgresprovider does not recognize connection

Tags: python, airflow

I am currently developing within a local `airflow standalone` devcontainer. I can see that the _CONN environment variable was correctly injected:

```
airflow@bbe914fbb436:~/dags$ printenv | grep DATA
AIRFLOW_CONN_PG_DATABASE="postgresql://user:xxx@myhost:5444?Test-DB"
```

excerpt from pg_test.py DAG

```
# DAG setup goes here.....

get_all_testme = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="select_test",
    postgres_conn_id="MY_DB",
    sql="""
        SELECT * from schema.testme
      """,
)
...
```

Airflow startup and running the tutorial DAG works fine, but when I try do to a modified version of the [example PG-DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/2.1.0/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html) i get

```
[2023-07-24, 09:40:31 UTC] {sql.py:265} INFO - Executing: 
            SELECT * from cts.testme
          
[2023-07-24, 09:40:31 UTC] {crypto.py:83} WARNING - empty cryptography key - values will not be stored encrypted.
[2023-07-24, 09:40:31 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'PG_DATABASE' for task execution.
[2023-07-24, 09:40:32 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py", line 266, in execute
    hook = self.get_db_hook()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py", line 181, in get_db_hook
    return self._hook
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cached_property.py", line 36, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py", line 144, in _hook
    hook = conn.get_hook(hook_params=self.hook_params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 359, in get_hook
    raise AirflowException(f'Unknown hook type "{self.conn_type}"')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Unknown hook type ""
```

Comment: Can you try updating your task definition to be `postgres_conn_id="PG_DATABASE"` instead of `MY_DB`?